# C# POST запрос с несколькими параметрами

Tags: c#, post

Пример запроса на сервер:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:0000/TST" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="cmd_conf">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="name">
  <input type="submit" value="cmd_getconfig single values">
</form>
```

Переписываю его на С#.
Если делаю такой запрос

```
string postData = "cmd=cmd_conf";
```

, то ответ приходит (получаю json-строку).

Не понимаю как правильно добавить к запросу `name`?
Попробовала через запятую, точку с запятой... не работает.

Comment: Через & пробовали?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, если так string postData = "cmd=cmd_conf&name=name";, то не работает

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, я ошиблась! работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string postData = "cmd=cmd_conf&name=name";
```